# Prevent Rcpp DataFrames of generating factors

Tags: r, dataframe, rcpp

When creating a DataFrame with Rcpp like this:

```
cppFunction('
    DataFrame testf(){CharacterVector character = {"B","D"}; 
    return(DataFrame::create(Named("foo")=character));}'
    )
```

The resulting DataFrame always converts the character vector to a factor.

```
df <- testf()
print(class(df$foo))
# > [1] "factor"
```

Is there a way to prevent this within C++?
Directly in `R` this is possible with the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I first saw this question, I thought it would surely be a duplicate, but after a search I don't think it is! Of course, this has been addressed at [Rcpp-devel](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2014-July/007844.html). I'll show that approach here; you add a named element `stringsAsFactors` set to `false`, similarly to R:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame testf(){
    CharacterVector character = {"B","D"}; 
    return(DataFrame::create(Named("foo")=character,
                             Named("stringsAsFactors") = false));
}
```

Then in action:

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp("so.cpp")
options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
df <- testf()
print(class(df$foo))
# [1] "character"
```

You may notice I explicitly set the default value of `stringsAsFactors` to `TRUE` via `options()`. That's because as of R 4.0.0 (which I'm currently running on my laptop), the default value is no longer `TRUE`, but `FALSE`.